# Let $n > 0 \in \mathbb Z$. Prove that $a, c$ leave the same remainder when divided by $n$ iff $a - c = nk$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Suppose $a - c = nk$ for some integer $k$. Then $- c = nk - a$ and $a = nk + c = nk + (nk - a) = n(2k) -a$.

Let $c = a - nk$ and $a = nk + c$. Then $a - c = nk + c - a + nk = c - c + nk = nk.$

Does that make sense?

Comment: There is an error in your first set of equalities: You substitute $-c$ for $c$.  Your conclusion, in that set of equalities, is too strong.  You start with $a-c=nk$ and somehow conclude that $a = nk$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try is wrong: you substituted $c$ by $nk-a$ but $c=a-nk$.

You should use the Euclidean division: there exist unique $q_a,r_a$ such that $a=nq_a+r_a$ and $0\le r_a<n$. Similarly, there exist unique $q_c,r_c$ such that $c=nq_c+r_c$ and $0\le r_c<n$.

Now, $a-c=nk$, that is
$$nk=n(q_a-q_c)+(r_a-r_c)$$

This implies that $r_a-r_b$ is a multiple of $n$. What can you deduce from this?

(Of course, all the variables involved are integer numbers).

EDIT: Since $0\le r_a\le n-1$ and $-n+1\le -r_b\le 0$, we have that $-n+1\le r_a-r_b\le n-1$. Since the only multiple of $n$ in this interval is $0$, then $r_a-r_b=0$.

Comment: So far all I know is division algorithm. Is it possible to prove the statement only knowing that unless Euclidean division and Division algorithm are the same thing?

Comment: The division algorithm is precisely what I have used.

Comment: Do we deduce that n divides $r_a - r_c$?

Comment: Can we say $r_a - r_c = -c$?